# What conditions imply the limit symbol pass through the function?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have some questions related limits such as $\lim f(g(x))=f(\lim g(x))$

I already know the continuity of $f$ and existence of limit at that point imply to pass limit through $f$.

For example,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \arctan(2^x/x) = \arctan(\lim_{x\to\infty}(2^x/x))$$

because of continuity of atan. However, $\arctan(\infty)$ does not exists.

What condition of $\arctan$ can make limit pass through even $\arctan$ doesn't have limit at infinity?

#### #

What I want to know contains below post(Corollary)
Thank you all
[Limit of a Composite Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272754/limit-of-a-composite-function)

Comment: $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= f(\lim_{x\to a} x)$ is pretty much the **definition** of "f is continuous at x= a"!

Answer (score 2):

I am answering for the case $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ and $g(x)=x$.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x)=\dfrac\pi2,$$

and

$$\arctan\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\right)$$ is not defined. Hence you simply cannot "make the limit pass through".

More generally,

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f\left(\lim_{x\to a}x\right)$$ provided $f$ is continous at $a$ and $\lim_{x\to a}x$ exists.